# preventing conflict between math symbols and html code

Tags: python, html

I want to present text out of math publications and every now and then I get something like

```
O(1/N_f) Corrections to the Thirring Model in 2<d<4<
```

The last part will be misinterpreted as html. I have to paste this text directly on the website allowing html. The reason why I need to allow html is that I use elasticsearch and I want to highlight the search results (elasticsearch puts  tags in the text). So can't just prevent html interpretation of the text.

However, I can pre-process the text to prevent any conflict. For example above all conflict is avoided by using

```
text.replace('<', " < ")
```

in python. However, this is far from optimal since
1. It will introduce spaces even when they are not needed
2. It only accounts for this particular collision between math symbols and html
Since I figure I am not the first person who encounters this I was wondering whether there is a general solution for such a problem?

Comment: Use `text.replace("<", "&lt;")`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `xml.sax.saxutils.escape` function:

```
import xml.sax.saxutils
escaped = xml.sax.saxutils.escape(text)
```

This will Escape '&', '<', and '>' in the text string.

Answer (score 0):

HTML has several characters with special meanings (including angle brackets), and is also usually represented in ASCII, so a good way to represent these types of special characters are needed.

In HTML, escape sequences are used to represent them. For example, a `&` character is represented by the named escape sequence `&amp;` or the numerical escape sequence `&#38;`. Only the most common special characters have named escape sequences.

Here's a [good](http://www.ascii.cl/htmlcodes.htm) list of sequences.